# Why Turn Collate Off

Tags: printing

Why would someone want to print multiple copies of a document and not collate them?

(So, in other words, why print a 5 page document in this order:  11111,22222,33333,44444,55555) instead of (12345,12345,12345,12345,12345)

Comment: This is to help me understand the purpose so I can help a user.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some documents may not be order-based.

For example, I may have a document where Page1 contains information for the East Coast branch, and Page2 contains information for the West Coast branch.

If I need 100 copies for each branch, collating would be a bad idea.